# How can i obtain onChange values?

Tags: javascript

I am following this tutorial

https://github.com/slawomir-zaziablo/range-slider/issues

I've already implemented the whole range slider, but I don't understand how the "onChange" method works

I quote from the web:

> onChange(callback) |  the callback function argument returns current
> selected values e.g mySlider.onChange(function (values) { // argument
> values represents current values });

I am using it this way:

```
    var mySlider = new rSlider({
        ...
    });
    
mySlider.onChange(function(val1, val2){
    console.log(val1);
console.log(val2);
});
```

What am I not doing wrong?

Comment: You can console.log(mySlider) and see anything callback on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var slider = new rSlider({
   target: '#slider',
   values: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
   range: true,
   set: [2010, 2013],
   onChange: function (vals) {
        console.log(vals);
   }
});
```